# How do I add new values to state using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

you need to add new values to the array, I can't understand what the problem is.
When you click on a checkbox, you need to get the id of this checkbox and write it to the array of answers for the corresponding question

```js
type Result = number;
interface Answer {
    result: Result[];
}
const answers: Answer[] = [];

questions.forEach(() => {
    answers.push({
        result: [],
    });
});
```

```js
const [currentAnswer, setNewAnswer] = useState<Answer[]>(answers)

const handleChange = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
    // console.log(typeof(currentAnswer),currentAnswer);
    if(e.target.checked){
        console.log(currentAnswer[currentQuestion].result.push(Number(e.target.id)));
            setNewAnswer(
                currentAnswer[currentQuestion].result.push(Number(e.target.id) // ERROR HERE
            )         
...
```

I got error

```js
const currentAnswer: Answer[]
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Answer[]>'
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Ефим Маргин, shouldn't line 1 read type Result = Number.  Number, not number, is a JavaScript type.

Comment: @ShamarYarde no, the correct typescript type is `number` not `Number` . See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean

Answer (score 2):

should use `.concat()` in this situation to return new array

`.push()` will only return new length which is number and incompatible with the type you make.

```
setNewAnswer(
     currentAnswer[currentQuestion].result.concat(Number(e.target.id)) // ERROR HERE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Mic Fung's answer, `push` mutates the existing array and doesn't return the new array.

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3]
myArray.push(4) // returns 4, which is the new array length
console.log(myArray) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`concat` doesn't mutate the existing array, but instead returns a new array

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3]
const myNewArray = myArray.concat(4)
console.log(myNewArray) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(myArray) // [1, 2, 3]
```

When working with React, you should avoid directly mutating the state. Instead, create new values and pass them to the `setState` function. This is why functions like `concat` are preferred over ones like `push`, as they avoid the mutation.